# Wine problem proportions

Tags: arithmetic, ratio

This problem is about rations and proportions .

Problem
A jar of full wine, extracted quarter(1/4) replacing it with water.
A second chance in the third part(1/3) of the content is extracted replacing it with water.
In a third and last chance is reextracted fifth(1/5) replacing it with water.
That proportion is in the end the wine and water ?

Thanks!

Comment: I supposed T=60k of all wine. First extracted 15k then i have a problem i don't agree water...is this 15k the same?

Comment: When extracting 1/3 of the mixture, you will extract 1/3 o fthe added water and - that is the point - 1/3 of the still contained wine

Comment: only wine? 
it is not necessary to add water ?

Comment: When you replace $\frac{1}{4}$ with water, that means that "1 minus 1/4 **of** what was already there is still wine, whereas 1/4 **of** what was already there is now water." (Hints not too discreet)

Comment: Try to find a formula since the changes are similar. Subsidary question ; does the result change if the operations are made in a different order ? having a formula may help

Answer (score 1):

Subtract 1/4 from 1

1-(1/4) which gives 3/4 wine left

3/4 + x =1, solve for x to find the water you need to add

3/4 wine + 1/4 water = 1

Remove 1/3 from the jar.

The amount that you remove is based on how much wine and water you have so they are weighted differently.

[(3/4)-(3/4)(1/3)] wine + [(1/4)-(1/4)(1/3)] water + x = 1

Again solve for x to find the amount of water that is needed to add back in.

The value is x = 1/3

(1/2) wine + (1/2) water = 1

Now remove the 1/5 of the liquid in the jar.

[(1/2)-(1/2)(1/5)] wine + [(1/2)-(1/2)(1/5)] water + x = 1

Solve for x gives, x=1/5

Add back in to get

(2/5) wine + (3/5) water = 1

These are the ratios.